# Java 7: Class as argument

Tags: java, class, arguments

I have a class named "Pencilcase", where the only instance variable is an `ArrayList<Pencil>`.

I have a method in it like this:

`public int qwerty(Pencilcase p)`

I've tried to do something like this: `for (Pencil pen : p)`

But I get an error, which says "for-each not applicable to expression type. Required: array or java.lang.Iterable; found Pencilcase".

Since it says that "Required: java.lang.iterable", I tried to use iterator, but still could not solve the problem. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use the for-each of Java you need to use `java.lang.Iterable` as the error message said. This means that the class you want to iterate needs to implement this interface. You have two ways to go about this.

**First Solution:** Access the internal list directly.

```
public class Pencilcase {
    public ArrayList<Pencil> list;
}
```

And iterate it like this:

```
public int qwerty(Pencilcase p) {
   for (Pencil pen : p.list) {
       ....
   }
}
```

Now this solution uses a public class variable. That is a bad thing. Also it doesn't look very fancy. So we have a

**Second Solution:** Implement Iterable

Now for that you need to alter your `Pencilcase` class to implement `Iterable`

```
public class Pencilcase implements java.lang.Iterable<Pencil> {
    private ArrayList<Pencil> list;

    @Override
    public Iterator<Pencil> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }
}
```

Using this class you can iterate over the Pencilcase instance directly.

This works because the `for`-loop basically fetches the iterator with the `iterator` function and uses this to fetch all the entries in the list.

So with this your loop can look like this:

```
public int qwerty(Pencilcase p) {
   for (Pencil pen : p) {
       ....
   }
}
```